# Unable to hide the <ul> tag inside the scroller Div

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jquery-cycle

This is my html code for horizontal scrolling

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="next_scrol1">&nbsp;</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="prev_scrol1">&nbsp;</a></div> 



<div id="index_scrol1">
<ul><li>
<p><strong>Position:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sr PHP Developer <br />
<strong>Job Code:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;SRPH124 <br />
</li></ul>
<ul><li>
<p><strong>Position:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sr PHP Developer <br />
<strong>Job Code:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;SRPH124 <br />
</li></ul>
</div>
```

In this Div "index_scrol1" i am not able to hide the ul. i am using **jquery.cycle.all.js** file for the scrolling. if i put like this

```
<ul style="display:none">
```

then also it ll not hide and keep scrolling. Please do the need ful in this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p><strong>Position:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sr PHP Developer <br />
  <strong>Job Code:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;SRPH124 </p>
  </li></ul>
  <ul><li>
  <p><strong>Position:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sr PHP Developer <br />
  <strong>Job Code:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;SRPH124 </p>
  </li></ul>
```

The CSS isn't necessary.

In my experience with the Jquery cycle, I've had similar problems, it just pays to make sure all of your html is solid, including having your **closing /p** at the end, **before your closing /li** tag.